# Creating a class library in visual studio code

Tags: .net-core, portable-class-library

It might be a silly question, Let's say I don't have a Windows OS, have a Linux. I have created a .Net core console app, also want to create a class library and reference it in console app. I can't find if i am able to do it also couldn't find a sample on Microsoft .Net core page. 
Is there an extension in vs code? Or isn't it possible with it?
If i am mistaken could you please guide me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best way to do it is from the console, since you are using the latest supported templates this way. VSCode also has an integrated terminal you can use for this.

```
$ dotnet new lib -o MyLib
$ dotnet new sln #assuming there is no .sln file yet. if there is, skip this
$ dotnet sln add MyLib/MyLib.csproj
$ cd MyConsoleApp
$ dotnet add reference ../MyLib/MyLib.csproj
```

If you need different frameworks, you can use the `-f` argument:

```
$ dotnet new lib -o MyLib -f netcoreapp2.0
```

or manually change the `<TargetFramework>` element inside the generated `.csproj` file.

Comment: This works perfectly however, it create a netstandard2.0 class library, how can i create a .net core class library

Comment: edited the answer to accommodate framework selection

Comment: I found that in Visual Studio Code v1.39.2 you have to use dotnet new classlib -o MyLib

Comment: There is a very useful VSCode extension called `.NET Core Add Reference`, it gives a GUI

Comment: Is it possible to add a new or existing cs file to a csproj? This seems to assume that all projects have one-and-only-one cs file.

Comment: The SDK-style projects automatically include very *.cs file in the directory hierarchy so no need to add them (unlike classic csproj for .net framework)