# Sharing classes across projects without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know this is by no means an unexplored issue, but my problem is pretty simple. I have an MVC application with all of my models, and I'm just finishing up a document generator for it. Ideally I would like to painlessly just inject it into this application after packaging the document generator separately, though I'm not sure if this is the best way of going about this.

The main issue is for my document generator I really need to access many models such as Discrepancy, WorkOrder, Part, etc. so they can be passed as arguments. What is the easiest, most loosely coupled way of sharing these classes across both my MVC application and my document generator? I'm using .NET Core and Visual Studio Code, so I don't have Visual Studio's UI to help add links or shared projects.

Comment: Turn it into a NuGet package?

Comment: You just want to make a class library and then reference it from your projects? Did you look up how to do that? What was the result of your attempts?

Comment: Smalles level to be referenced is a project. Put the classes you use on several places into one project and add references to the project

Comment: @mason I looked at numerous solutions, they all either provide Visual Studio specific options or they seem vague(to me, at least). I understand how to make class libraries and reference in a local directory, but how would I specifically go about sharing a class library across different projects in different directories? Thank you for the help

Comment: Adding on to @mason 's comment, here's a .NET Core way to create a class library without the Visual Studio UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504322/creating-a-class-library-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @KevinLamb I know how to reference class libraries and solutions, the problem is I don't know the ideal way to share a class across two independent projects here, appreciate the help.

Comment: @KevinLamb, sample in linked question is outdated, template and parameter names are changed a bit. But still provide good example of how it could be done.

Comment: You could create a NuGet package. There's plenty of directions out there for how to do that.

Comment: @mason That may be the only real solution I have honestly. It adds a bit more complexity but I suppose I may HAVE to go that route. Thank you for the help, I was hoping there was a simpler way really.

Comment: @Fabio Ah true, missed that

Comment: Simpler version of NuGet package is having separate project (dll) which other projects can reference. In this case NuGet package is an overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know the ideal way to share a class across two independent
>   projects here

Ideal way is to create new project with classes you want to share and reference it from both projects.

In the root directory of your solution

```powershell
dotnet new classlib -n MyModels -t netstandard2.0
```

Move model classes into new project
Then in document generator directory reference just created models project

```powershell
dotnet add reference ../MyModels/MyModels.csproj
```

Done

You can create a solution file to represent your projects

```powershell
dotnet sln MySolution.sln add MyModels/MyModels.csproj Documents/Documents.csproj
```

Pretty sure there are some extensions for Visual Studio Code to handle c# projects and solutions

For example: `vscode-solution-explorer`

Comment: I guess my main concern here is how do I do this not just locally, as this wouldn't work with a github repository would it? Apologies if my question is confusing.

Comment: 1. I would suggest to keep all solution related projects in one repository. 2. If you have separate repository for every project - see option number 1 :)

Comment: If you have separate repository for every project, you have two options: 1. Create new project in one of the repository. 2. Create new repository for shared projects.  In both options you must be sure that all required repositories are cloned locally and their relative location remain same - so project references will work